# % of baseline variation explained by did estimator

Tags: interpretation, difference-in-difference

I am running regressions of the type:

$y_{it}=\alpha + \delta T_{it} + \gamma X_{it}+ \lambda_{t} + \epsilon_{it}$

where $T_{it}=1$ for some observations for $t>\bar{t}$ and $T_{it}=0$ otherwise.

This is a very common diff-in-diff estimator and I'm interested in estimating the parameter $\delta$.

In many papers using the same kind of estimator, they would give the percentage of the baseline variation in the dependent variable that is explained by the change in $T_{it}$. In other words, they would calculate how much $\delta$ amounts for the observed variation of the dependent variable since the initial date.

Is there a simple formula to calculate this percentage? I can't find one convincing and concise explanation on how to do that.

Thank you very much for your help.